# progress view in alamo fire will not update when downloading file in swift 3

Tags: swift3, download, alamofire, uialertcontroller, uiprogressview

I want to download a file with alamo fire and using alert with progress to show it but the progress will not move when alamo fire progress.fractionCompleted increased I use static var to equal progres.fractionCompleted but it doesn't worked too 
here is my codes

```
 let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination()

        Alamofire.download("example.com", to: destination).downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { (progress) in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            sixthLevelViewController.progressdownload = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Downloading", message: "please wait", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let progressDownload : UIProgressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)

            progressDownload.setProgress(ViewController.progressdownload, animated: true)
            progressDownload.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: 250, height: 0)

            alertController.view.addSubview(progressDownload)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
            } .validate().responseData { ( response ) in
                print(response.destinationURL!.lastPathComponent)
        }
```

**Remember that this will work well and the problem is just updating progress view **

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong: according to the [latest](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) Alamofire documents I make an example to show how you can modify your code:

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                                                .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath, isDirectory: true)
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("myfile.pdf")

        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories]) }

func requestDownloadInfo(url:String) {
            Alamofire.download(url, to :destination)
                .downloadProgress(queue: utilityQueue) { progress in
                    let progressDic = ["progress" : progress.completedUnitCount, "total" :  progress.totalUnitCount, "fraction" : progress.fractionCompleted] as [String:Any]
                    // here you can show your alert using fraction value..
                }
                .responseData { response in
                  // check your file after download or check errors...
                }
}
```

Comment: swift doesn't let me to run the application because of the RetunzAPIProgress

Comment: ok forget about this I used another code But there is another problem please help me with that and after that fixed I will answer this question by my self here is the link of that question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137799/why-alamo-fire-download-progress-in-alert-will-flashing-and-the-behind-screen-st